# Adding an atom to a list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I want to add atoms to the end of a list and I also want the original list to change. I've written this small program, but it doesn't mutate the list. Why is that and how can I change it. PS: I'm new to scheme.

```
(define (append! l1 l2)    
   (set! l1 (append l1 (list l2)) )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a syntactic extension:

```
(define-syntax-rule (append! l1 at)
  (set! l1 (append l1 (list at))))
```

then

```
> (define l1 '(1 2 3))
> (append! l1 4)
> l1
'(1 2 3 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is that you're only changing a function's parameter, but the list "outside" of the function remains unchanged after the function exits. We can  modify the list in-place using `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`, but it's a bit tricky because first we have to find the right `cons` cell to modify, and return the head of the list:

```
(define (append! lst atom)
  (let ((head lst))
    (let loop ((lst lst))
      (cond ((null? lst) (list atom))
            ((null? (cdr lst))
             (set-cdr! lst (list atom))
             head)
            (else (loop (cdr lst)))))))

(define l1 '(1 2 3 4))
l1
=> '(1 2 3 4)

(append! l1 5)
l1
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Or even better, we can forget about mutating lists in place and embrace a functional programming style, which is the recommended way when using Scheme:

```
(define l1 '(1 2 3 4))

(define (append-tail lst atom)    
  (append lst (list atom)))

(define l2 (append-tail l1 5))

l1
=> '(1 2 3 4)
l2
=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: Well the problem is that I want to use this function in another one, so this doesn't help me much.

Comment: @pesho I updated my answer with an implementation closer to what you intended in the first place, but trust me: in Scheme this is not the right way to do things, the version that doesn't mutate the list in place is recommended - as you said, you're just learning Scheme, so it'd be better if you started to do things the right way.

Answer (score 0):

There are `set!` that mutates the binding but not the value and there are `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` mutates a value if it's a pair.

`set!` works as altering an assignment. So if you have `x` and `y` both being a value `"value"` and use `set!` to change `x` to `"anothervalue"`. If you have a procedure and assign a different value to one of the arguments you are redefining the local name, not changing the variable that was passed to that procedure.

`set-car!` and `set-cdr` works on pairs. Thus they mutate values and have nothing to do with the variables.

Eg:

```
(define x (list 1 2 3))    ; x is (1 2 3)
(define y x)               ; y is (1 2 3)
(define z y)               ; z is (1 2 3)

;; changing the binding of z
(set! z (append x '(1)))   ; z is (1 2 3 1) while x and y still are (1 2 3)

;; changing the value of x
(set-car! x 2)             ; both x and y are now (2 2 3)
```

With that in mind you can alter a variable, but remember that that very variable can have shared structure with other variables and thus you might change more variables than you originally though by using `set-cdr!`

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (rnrs mutable-pairs))

(define (append-elt! lst value)
  (when (null? lst)
    (assertion-violation 'append! "lst cannot be null" lst))

  (let loop ((lst lst))
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
        (set-cdr! lst (list value))
        (loop (cdr lst)))))

(define q (append y y)) ; We make a copy of y with y as shared tail
(append-elt! q 'a)      ; we change the last pair of q which also is the last pair of y and z
q ; ==> (1 2 3 1 2 3 a)
x ; ==> (1 2 3 a)
z ; ==> (1 2 3 a)
```